# Limit point and identity theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

On a current problem sheet I've read the following: Let $G\subseteq\mathbb C$ be a domain and $f:G\to\mathbb C$ holomorphic. Let $(z_n)_n$ be a sequence with a limit point in $G$ and $f(z_n)=0$ for all $n$, then $f(z)\equiv 0$ for all $z\in G$ according to the identity theorem.

My question is this: Is this even true? The sequence $z_n=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ has the limit point $0\in\mathbb C$ and $f(z)=z$ satisfies the condition, however $f$ is not equal to $0$ on $\mathbb C$.
As far as I know the identity theorem needs limit points of **sets** to be applied. So the statement would be true if we said the following: Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence such that $\{z_n:n\in\mathbb N\}\subseteq G$ has a limit point in $G$. Now if $f(z_n)=0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, the identity theorem implies $f\equiv 0$ on $G$.

Am I correct?

Comment: $0$ is not a limit point of $z_n=0$

Comment: The definition of a limit point:"Every neighborhood contains an element of the topological space other than the point itself" The  constant sequence $0$ has a limit, but the concept of a limit point is different from that

Comment: In all the definitions I found it is: Some $a\in\mathbb C$ is a limit point of a sequence $(z_n)$ if every neighborhood of $a$ contains infinitely many elements of the sequence. Only for limit points of sets it is required that these points differ from $a$.

Comment: infinitely many elements, not one element with infinitely many indices, then the definition is compatible to that of a limit point of sets.

Comment: So the sequence $z_{2n}=1$ and $z_{2n+1}=-1$ has no limit points? That's nonsensical to me.

Comment: I see the problem, by the definition I learned these are limits of subsequences, but no limit points or accumulation points, may be [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071508/what-is-the-difference-between-the-limit-of-a-sequence-and-a-limit-point-of-a-se) is of interest to You.

Comment: Isn't there some common ground? Does the sequence $z_n=(-1)^n$ have limit points or not?

Comment: No limit points, but two isolated points.

Comment: Well, I have two books on complex analysis here that say otherwise. Now I know what got me so confused... It's just a definition everybody does differently.

Comment: Yes, I read some confusing definitions too. I would suggest to make the difference:"every neighborhood contains elements ( in the sequence or set) other than the point itself: limit point" "there is an neighborhood that only contains the point itself: isolated point". Anyway good You pointed that out!+1

Comment: Thanks for clarifying though! If you are interested in the points associated with the green checkmark you can just post some random answer and I will reward it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The discussion in the comments shows that there is no consensus about the concept of a *limit point a of a sequence*. This is not a new discussion. Probably the reason for dissenting opinions is that a *limit point $p$ of a set $S$* definitely requires the existence of a point $q \in S \setminus \{ p \}$ in any neighborhood of $p$. See for example [Limit point of sequence vs limit point of the set containing all point of the sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/577198), [what is diffrernce between limit point of sequence and limit of sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1931753).

Thus the whole problem is a sort a linguistic problem.

My personal opinion is that RedLantern's interpretation is correct. See also https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-differences-between-limit-and-limit-point. I think the limit of a sequence (if it exists) deserves to be called a limit point of the sequence, and this applies to constant sequences.